# Using grep to remove from verbose call and saving in a shell script function

Tags: unix, grep, sh

I have a curl put request that I can use some unix command to see the `stdout` and `stderr` from.

If I add the line `2>&1 | grep -v "Authorization"` At the end of my curl request, I can see the `verbose` output from my curl in my CLI minus a line that starts with "Authorization"

I tried creating a function with the above command, but when I call that function at the end of my  curl request (like below) it no longer removes the "Authorization" line.

```
function remove_item_from_verbose { 
  2>&1 | grep -v "Authorization" 
}

echo -e "\n +++ Creating '$TENANT' tenant:\n"
# Create tenant
curl -L -X PUT "http://localhost:$HOST_PORT/admin/v2/tenants/$TENANT" \
    --verbose \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    --header "Authorization: Bearer $AUTHORIZATION" \
    --data-raw "{\"allowedClusters\": [\"$CLUSTER\"]}" remove_item_from_verbose
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK functions do work like that.  What you are trying to so is add extra details to your command.  You can do it like that:

```
#!/bin/bash

remove_item_from_verbose="2>&1 | grep -v \"Authorization\""

echo -e "\n +++ Creating '$TENANT' tenant:\n"

# Create tenant
eval curl -L -X PUT "http://localhost:$HOST_PORT/admin/v2/tenants/$TENANT" \
    --verbose \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    --header "Authorization: Bearer $AUTHORIZATION" \
    --data-raw "{\"allowedClusters\": [\"$CLUSTER\"]}" "$remove_item_from_verbose"
```

Like this, `$remove_item_from_verbose` becomes a suffix of your command.
Note the addition of `eval` in front of `curl`, it is required to have this suffix treated as part of the command.

Comment: Thanks for this. It seems promising. I'm getting a series of `Could not resolve host` errors at the moment however.

Comment: That is a DNS error, nothing to do with your question.  Make sure the hostname you use in your curl is valid.

Comment: But the request is valid under the original format. Returns a `200` and I can see that the new tenant is created when I use a `GET` request.